# Easy Tooltip content change via Javascript

Tags: javascript, tooltip

Can you help me with changing the content of Easy Tooltip dynamically via Javascript? I tried almost everything:

```
document.getElementById('easy_tooltip').innerHTML(tooltipContent);
$("#easy_tooltip").html(tooltipContent);
$("#easy_tooltip").content(tooltipContent);
```

But it doesn't work. I cannot access the content of that element.

The example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7UZ7/).

Thank you.

Comment: In the example, the `change_tooltip` function is never called. Have a look at the Chrome Developer Tools console.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k7UZ7/9/ - repaired version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this plugin is built is to use the `title` attribute of your element, so you can rather update your HTML code like this :

```
<a href="#" id="tooltip-1" class="tooltip" title="Tooltip 1">Tooltip 1</a>
<br />
<a href="#" id="tooltip-2" class="tooltip" title="Tooltip 2">Tooltip 2</a>
```

(See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/UGrkq/1/))

And if you need a dynamic content, you can always modify this attribute with jQuery :

```
$("#tooltip-1").attr("title", "mycontent");
```

Comment: Thank you, so i need to put ID on all links.

Comment: Only if you need to change dynamically the tooltip content! In all cases, you don't need it. And you can also use selectors like `$("a:eq(0)")` if needed...

Comment: Thank you, you are a pure guru!