# How to change tooltip of a div tag through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tooltip

currently I am using Jquery to append text on to tooltip like this;

```
$('#test').attr('title', $('#test').attr('title') + ' text to append');
```

What I would like to know is, how can I achieve this via javascript?

Any help is welcomed, I did some research but had no luck.

[Easy Tooltip content change via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602853/easy-tooltip-content-change-via-javascript)

[Changing the tooltip of button dynamically in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117925/changing-the-tooltip-of-button-dynamically-in-html)

Comment: My initial thought was "But that *is* javascript." Then I realised that you seem to be asking how to do it without using a library?

Comment: Yea, so currently the apporach I am using uses jquery library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this it work same like you have done in jquery

```
document.getElementById("test").title = document.getElementById("test").title + 'text to append';
```